# Remove Orphaned Items In A Hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of items in MySQL, connected through a column "parent_id".

Let's assume the columns are:  id, name, parent_id

If one of my users deletes an item high in the hierarchy, I need to delete all of its children.  So, two part question:

1) Is there an effective and efficient MySQL call that will return ID's for all items where its parent no longer exists?

2) In PHP, I'm thinking I can get these orphaned ID's from MySQL into an array, then run a foreach loop and delete each?

Much thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what the original author had in mind was something in the lines of hierarchical queries.

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have native support for hierarchical queries (unlike, for example Oracle, where you could use `CONNECT BY` to achieve what you want).

Probably the easiest way to remove all orphans would be to execute a query like:

```
  SELECT t1.id 
    FROM table t1
      LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

This would yield you all rows from `table` where their parent doesn't exist.

Pair this with a PHP script that keeps executing the query and deleting any results, and after a couple of iterations your table should be free of orphans (this whole thing can probably be merged into one DELETE statement you could just execute in a while loop).

You need to execute the select-delete multiple times because of transitivity -- consider a situation where an orphan is parent to another record; with the first iteration you'd remove the first orphan, making the next record in chain an orphan.

Also, make sure you explicitly skip the head of your hierarchy, otherwise you'll end up with an empty table (as the head is, by definition, an orphan).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using InnoDB, you should look into [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) which take care of this for you by using the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option when you are setting your foreign key relationships.

An example from the docs:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

With that in place, if you were to do add a parent and a matching child row like this:

```
INSERT INTO parent (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO child (id, parent_id) VALUES (1,1);
```

And then removed the parent like this:

```
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 1;
```

You will find the matching child record to be gone. This is, in my opinion, the best way to do it.

**EDIT**: To do this within 1 table, you would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(250) not null,
    parent_id INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Then if you add two rows, one referencing the other:

```
INSERT INTO parent (id,name,parent_id)
VALUES ('1', 'Test 1', NULL), ('2', 'Test 2', '1')
```

Then delete the parent row of the two:

```
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 1;
```

You will find that it deletes the child row with `parent_id` of 1.

Comment: All of my items are in a single table.

Comment: This still works with relationships in a single table. I'll add an example in a second.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is linearly hierarchical (only one parent relation per node), and high-read, low-write, you might consider migrating it to a Modified Preorder Tree Traversal structure.  It sounds scary, but it's actually very neat.  There's a great article on it here:  http://www.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/1/

Not only is retrieving data from such a structure extremely efficient (single SELECT and you get all the children), you'll be able to delete a whole branch of the tree in a single DELETE statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

RIGHT JOINS are usually used to find orphans in other databases. But this is possible also with a LEFT JOIN.

[Here is](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/mysql-mysql-joins-using-left-join-and-right-join-to-find-orphan-rows.html) a very nicely layed out article about getting orphan rows in MySQL

Comment: My items are in a single table.  Would I join on itself?

Answer (score 1):

Another option (if you are not using InnoDB, +1 Paolo) is to use [Delete Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) on the parent MySQL table.

Remember, when using a delete trigger, the deleting row is referenced by **OLD**.  Here is an example trigger.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER delete_clean BEFORE DELETE ON Parent
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE * FROM Parent WHERE Parent.parent_id = OLD.id;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```